# How to write this SQL Statement to join 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:-
Register(Stu_id, name, address,....,status),
Applicant_Choice(Stu_id,Sub_id1,Sub_id2,Sub_id3) for 3 selected subjects
Subjects(Sub_id,Subject_name,....) for subject names

I want to extract report in the form :- id,name, address,... 3 subject names for the Sub_id1,Sub_id2,Sub_id3 present in Applicant table where Register.status = 6.

So far I am using loops to generate the subject names for each record. But There will be 1000 records in Applicant table. So in that case so much queries to generate a pdf file will be too much!!! Can anybody show me how to write this query? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one out:

```
  select r.stu_id, r.name, r.address, s1.subject_name, s2.subject_name, s3.subject_name
  from register r
  inner join applicant_choice a
    on r.stu_id = a.stu_id
  inner join subjects s1
    on a.sub_id1 = s1.sub_id
  inner join subjects s2
    on a.sub_id2 = s2.sub_id
  inner join subjects s3
    on a.sub_id3 = s3.sub_id
  where r.status = 6;
```

Example fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5daaa/3

Comment: How could I thank you Sir?. This is working and helped me a lot!!